# Function won't work with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

So I am adding in buttons to my wysiwyg(TinyMCE) on wordpress. There's a function that is called to add the buttons to the button array. Inside that function I created a new loop because there are quite a few buttons to add. There must be something wrong with my loop because it throws up errors while just inserting the code manually returns none.

```
 //Add button to the button array.

function register_button($buttons) {
//Use PHP 'array_push' function to add the columns button to the $buttons array

       $columnNum = array('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven');

       for($i=0;$i<11;$i++){

           array_push($buttons, '"'.$columnNum[$i].'_col"');
           array_push($buttons, '"'.$columnNum[$i].'_col_first"');
           array_push($buttons, '"'.$columnNum[$i].'_col_last"');
       }


//Return buttons array to TinyMCE
   return $buttons;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is $buttons an array?

Comment: This seems to work : http://eval.in/14976

Comment: What are the errors it's giving you?

Comment: if $buttons is array, why not pass parameter as reference?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

did you check if `$buttons` is an array? because if not, `array_push` will fail.

if you are sure $buttons is an array you can try this:

```
$buttons[] = '"'.$columnNum[$i].'_col"';
```

by the way: are you sure it that it should not be `$columnNum[$i].'_col'` without the double quotes?

anyway there are some obvius ways to optimize your code e.g.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($columNum); $i++){
```

Comment: Seems like it was my suspect quotes that caused the problems. Now it's working. But oddly enough count($columNum) breaks it. I don't plan on adding more buttons so I think I'll just leave that though.

Comment: Why would you need to add quotes in the first place, though?!

Comment: Because I was using array_push before and simplifying the quotes seemed to fixed it. $buttons[] = $columnNum[$i].'_col' is what I ended up with. Haha it's been a long week.